# No matching constructor for initialization of 'Phone' (CPP)

Tags: c++, constructor, int

edit: Resolved. I'm an idiot. I put "" around the number 64.

beginner programmer here with a C++ problem relating to **Constructors**. When I compile (via Xcode) I get this error:

> *No matching constructor for initialization of 'Phone'*

I'm teaching myself through this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/vLnPwxZdW4Y?t=12340

Code listed below, but I also have a **screenshot** if it makes it easier to read. [SCREENSHOT INCLUDING ERROR MESSAGES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9AEd.png)

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

// Creating a Class for the type of phone.
class Phone {
public:
std::string manufacturer;
std::string model;
int capacity; //in GB

// Creating a Constructor. This will be called whenever we create a "Phone" object.
Phone(std::string aManufacturer, std::string aModel, int aCapacity) 
  {
    manufacturer = aManufacturer;
    model = aModel;
    capacity = aCapacity;
  }
};

int main()
{
// Objects
Phone iPhone("Apple", "6s", "64"); // This is where the error occurs
}
```

Comment: `Phone` expects an `int` as `aCapacity`, but you're passing `"64"`. Try `Phone iPhone("Apple", "6s", 64);`

Comment: Yep this fixed it. Now I feel like an idiot. Thanks @songyuanyao!

Answer (score 1):

You have defined "aCapacity" as an integer.

You need write:

```
int main()
{
    Phone iPhone("Apple", "6s", 64);
}
```

that is ... 64 without quotation marks.